# A RawComparator for comparing TextPair byte representations

Tags: hadoop, io

There is one class in the book Hadoop:The Definitive Guide:

```
public static class Comparator extends WritableComparator {
    private static final Text.Comparator TEXT_COMPARATOR = new Text.Comparator();

    public Comparator() {
        super(TextPair.class);
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(byte[] b1, int s1, int l1, byte[] b2, int s2, int l2) {
        try {
            int firstL1 = WritableUtils.decodeVIntSize(b1[s1]) + readVInt(b1, s1);
            int firstL2 = WritableUtils.decodeVIntSize(b2[s2]) + readVInt(b2, s2);
            int cmp = TEXT_COMPARATOR.compare(b1, s1, firstL1, b2, s2, firstL2);
            if (cmp != 0) {
                return cmp;
            }
            return TEXT_COMPARATOR.compare(b1, s1 + firstL1, l1 - firstL1,b2, s2 + firstL2, l2 - firstL2);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
    }
}

static {
    WritableComparator.define(TextPair.class, new Comparator());
}
```

The part which I do not understand is :

```
int firstL1 = WritableUtils.decodeVIntSize(b1[s1]) + readVInt(b1, s1);
```

As explained in the book:

> "The subtle part of this code is calculating firstL1 and firstL2, the
>   lengths of the first Text field in each byte stream. Each is made up
>   of the length of the variable-length integer (returned by
>   `decodeVIntSize()` on `WritableUtils`) and the value it is encoding
>   (returned by `readVInt()`)."

From my understanding, the expression `WritableUtils.decodeVIntSize(b1[s1])` is just the length of the first text field(number of bytes) and the expression `readVInt(b1, s1)` is the content of the field, this is where I am getting confused.
Can someone explain this to me?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A simple test like the following will clarify:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream outDat = new DataOutputStream(out);
    TextPair tp1 = new TextPair("Pig", "Li");
    Comparator cmp = new TextPair.Comparator();
    tp1.write(outDat);
    byte[] b1 = out.toByteArray();
    outDat.close();
    System.out.println(WritableUtils.decodeVIntSize(b1[0]));
    System.out.println(WritableComparator.readVInt(b1, 0)); }
```

The output is:

> 1
>
> 3

This is because the 1 stands for the length of the variable-length header (1 byte) because only 1 byte is needed to contain the number "3" And the 3 represents the length of the text, which is 3 characters, and therefore 3 bytes (all three chars can each be represented by a single byte).

Answer (score 0):

Please note here it uses VInt instead of Int. And VInt uses the first byte to indicate how many bytes follow. decodeVIntSize(b1[s1]) gets the number of bytes for the VInt, while readVInt(b1, s1) reads the actual number of bytes for the String.